# Detecting serial port settings

Tags: python, serial-port, communication

From time to time I suddenly have a need to connect to a device's console via its serial port. The problem is, I never remember what port settings (baud rate, data bits, stop bits, etc...) to use with each particular device, and documentation never seems to be lying around when it's really needed.

I wrote a Python script, which uses a simple brute-force method (i.e. iterates over all possible settings, sends some test input and displays the response for a human to decide if it makes sense ), but:

- it takes a long time to complete
- does not always work (perhaps port reset/timeout issues)
- just does not seem like a proper way to do this :)

So the question is: does anyone know of a procedure to auto-detect what port settings the remote device is using?

Comment: I would just add some features to your python script, such that it contains a dictionary that maps your device's names to their settings.  Each time you figure something out, update your script and you won't have to try and remember next time.

Comment: @wroniasty Can you attach your script here please? :)

Answer (score 1):

Although part 1 is no direct answer to your question:

There are devices, which just have a autodetection (called Auto-bauding) method included, that means: Send a character using your current settings (9k6, 115k2, ..) to the device and chances are high that the device will answer with your (!) settings. I've seen this on HP switches.

Second approach: try to re-order the connection possibilities. E.g. chances are high that the other end uses 9k6 with no hardware handshake, but less that it uses 38k4 with software Xon/Xoff.

If you break down your tries into just a few, the "brute force" method will be much more efficient.